# How to replace Spring Boot 1.3.x 404 error page with custom error html page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Currently I am using Spring Boot v 1.3.x 
I have added error html page as below:
[image: Folder Structure for error html page]

But still default whitelable message is not getting replace for 404 with my html page.

It is working in Spring Boot v 2.x but I wanted to use Spring Boot v 1.3.x

Query:
Is there any way to override default 404 error page

Answer (score 0):

This was added in Spring Boot 1.4, so it is normal that it does not work in Spring Boot 1.3: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-1.4-release-notes#convention-based-error-pages

Also note that [Spring Boot 1.x should no longer be used](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/06/it-is-time-goodbye-spring-boot-1-x).

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve custom error page handling ?